# Sample dump SQL Server database

Tags: sql-server-2008

Does anyone have any tips for dumping a sample of a SQL Server database? Or the best way to do it?

I am working with a database with many tables and would only want to take a sample of it.

Comment: Try the import/export wizard, or the generate scripts. You can select which table(s) to move/script and include the data.

Comment: Please explain what you mean by "dumping a sample". Show us an example result.

Comment: "dumping a sample" would refer to if I had a table called customers and didnt want all the contents of the table but similar to a mysql limit. select * from customers limit 500; I could bash script that in MySQL. Not sure in MSSQL how to do that. Obviously I would want more than one table in this case.

Comment: You mean something like `SELECT TOP 500 * FROM Customers`?

Comment: @DourHighArch sort of - I am looking to do that but on a much larger scale. I have about 200 tables and I would like the TOP 500 records from each one.

Comment: That's a pretty important requirement you didn't explain. How do you know which tables you want records from? We're not telepathic, you must provide enough information to answer you.

Comment: My initial statement after the question above reads as "I am working with a database with many tables and would only want to take a sample of it." So no telepathy was required there. I am going to use @AaronBertrand's suggestion as that is most helpful. Thank you for your time.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could use the command-line bcp and its -L (last row) switch.  Script something like this from the database metadata, eg:

```
SET NOCOUNT ON

SELECT 'bcp "yourDatabase.' + SCHEMA_NAME(schema_id) + '.' + name + '" out c:\temp\' + SCHEMA_NAME(schema_id) + '.' + name + '.bcp -SyourServer -T -n -L 500'
FROM sys.tables
```

Then run the output on the command-line.

Comment: Thanks @wBob I am going to try that as well.